# Access remote directory from another domain with c#

Tags: c#, directory, remote-access, impersonation

I need to access the following directory found from another domain into my c# program. How shall I proceed? Should I user Impersonate method?

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\testweb\folder\test", "*.txt");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing that wou will need to programatically (if that's how you wanna solve it) create a connection to the domain with a proper user. You can do it using this class:

```
   public class MprWrapper
    {
        [DllImport("Mpr.dll")]
        private static extern int WNetUseConnection(
            IntPtr hwndOwner,
            _NETRESOURCE lpNetResource,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpUserID,
            int dwFlags,
            string lpAccessName,
            string lpBufferSize,
            string lpResult
            );

        struct _NETRESOURCE
        {
            public int dwScope;
            public int dwType;
            public int dwDisplayType;
            public int dwUsage;
            public string lpLocalName;
            public string lpRemoteName;
            public string lpComment;
            public string lpProvider;
        }


        public static void WNetUseConnection(string remoteName, string user, string pass)
        {
            _NETRESOURCE myStruct = new _NETRESOURCE
            {
                dwType = 1, //it's a disk (0 is any, 2 is printer)
                lpRemoteName = remoteName
            };

            int error = WNetUseConnection(new IntPtr(0), myStruct, pass, user, 0, null, null, null);
            if (error != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("That didn't work either");
            }
            // if we reach here then everything worked!!!
        }
    }
```

You connect with

```
 MprWrapper.WNetUseConnection(@"\\DomainAddressHere", @"Domain\User", "Password1");
```

Then your getfiles method will work fine. This potentially leaves an open connection (but it doesn't create more than one) but anyway you may wanna create code to close it, handle everything correctly, etc. This is merely a starting point.

Comment: Where should I create this connection?

Comment: @velvt Before calling the method